# gregexpr - how to maintain order of list of numbers extracted in r

Tags: r, regex, dplyr

I have the following `dataframe`

| patient_id | value |
| --- | --- |
| patient1 | 4.3 |
| patient2 | 4.2 |
| patient3 ​ | <1.0 |

However the `value` is not `numeric` and I need it to be.

I was able to use `gregexpr` (see code snippet) and it worked to convert `value` into `numeric`, however how do I keep the `value` attached to `patient_id`, in other words, how do I maintain the order?

```
gfg <- patient_id$value        

gfg_numbers <- regmatches(gfg, gregexpr("[[:digit:]]+", gfg))
as.numeric(unlist(gfg_numbers))
value_num <- as.numeric(unlist(gfg_numbers))

as.data.frame(value_num)

value_num_df <- as.data.frame(value_num)
```

Comment: but the `value` in your example is numeric?!

Comment: It is not numeric! There are spaces and other characters I cannot get rid of, hence my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `parse_number`

```
library(readr)
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(value = parse_number(value))
```

output:

```
patient_id  value
  <chr>       <dbl>
1 "patient1"    4.3
2 "patient2 "   4.2
3 "patient3"    1
```

data:

```
df <- tribble(
~patient_id,    ~value,
"patient1",     "4.3",
"patient2 ",    "4.2",
"patient3",     "< 1.0")
```

Answer (score 1):

The order is in fact maintained.  The problem with your current approach is that your regex extraction pattern is wrong, and should be `\d+(?:\.\d+)?`.  Consider this updated script:

```r
df <- data.frame(patient_id=c("patient1", "patient2"), value=c("4.3", "4.2"))
gfg <- df$value        
gfg_numbers <- regmatches(gfg, gregexpr("\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?", gfg))
value_num <- as.numeric(unlist(gfg_numbers))
value_num

[1] 4.3 4.2   # order is being maintained here
```